# Sequelize upsert is omitting missing fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I am using Sequelize 5 in my node js app. I am using `Model.upsert()` to update/create rows based on the user input. my problem is that Sequelize is always ommitting null/undefined attributes . I tried to add `omitNull:false` to my sequelize config but it is still omitting them. Is there a fix for this behaviour ?

Comment: did you spell the option correctly?  `omitNull:false`  (only one 'm').  Also, does the attribute in question have `allowNull: true` in the model?

Comment: yes I checked the spelling it is correct on my app (I made a typo). I also checked that the column have `allowNull:true`

Comment: Can you post your `upsert()` code?  I ran a little test using `
        Review.upsert({
            id : 110,
            updatedAt: null
            }
        )` 
which did change the `updatedAt` field from a date value to null....